# Using python scrapy to extract links from a webpage

Tags: python, scrapy

I am a beginner with python and using scrapy to extract links from the following webpage
http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2015_games.html.

The code that I have written is

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from basketball.items import BasketballItem

class BasketballSpider(CrawlSpider):

   name = 'basketball'
   allowed_domains = ['basketball-reference.com/']
   start_urls = ['http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2015_games.html']
   rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['http://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/^\w+$']), 'parse_item')]

   def parse_item(self, response):
       item = BasketballItem()
       item['url'] = response.url
       return item
```

I run this code through the command prompt, but the file created does not have any links. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rules = [
         Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='boxscores/\w+'), callback='parse_item')
]
```

Answer (score 2):

It cannot find the links, fix you regular expression in the rule:

```
rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='boxscores/\w+'))
]
```

Also, you don't have to set the `callback` when it is called `parse_item` - it is a default.

And `allow` can be set as a string also.

Comment: the start URL is different from the links I am trying to extract..eg. the web pge from where I am extracting the link is 'http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2015_games.html' and the lniks I am extracting are of the format http://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201410280LAL.html..what changes do I need to do to the codes..

Comment: @anandsingh Did this answer help?  Please mark it as "accepted" if so, or if you can post the answer that worked for you and accept that.